# Error java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed when i display dataframe (created joining others dataframes)

Tags: dataframe, join, display, databricks, assertion

I'm joining three data frames and all it's ok, but when I call to "display" method at the final data frame (joining three previous dataframe) databricks return this error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed
```

I'm using:

```
%fs head dbfs:/databricks-datasets/iot-stream/data-user/

%fs ls dbfs:/databricks-datasets/iot-stream/data-user/
```

Could someone help me? Thanks!

These are the data frames schemas:

**df_MaximasCalorias**

- ID: long (nullable = true)
- Max_Calorias: double (nullable = true)

**df_MinCalorias**

- user_id: long (nullable = true)
- Min_Calorias: double (nullable = true)

**df_MediaCalorias**

- user_id: long (nullable = true)
- Media_Calorias: double (nullable = true)

**Dataframe = dfCalorias (join df_MaximasCalorias and df_MinCalorias)**

- ID: long (nullable = true)
- Max_Calorias: double (nullable = true)
- Min_Calorias: double (nullable = true)

**Dataframe = dfCaloriasFinal (join dfCalorias and df_MediaCalorias)**

- ID: long (nullable = true)
- Max_Calorias: double (nullable = true)
- Min_Calorias: double (nullable = true)
- Media_Calorias: double (nullable = true)

**And this is the complete code:**

## Change columns names

```
df_MaximasCalorias = df_MaximasCalorias.withColumnRenamed("user_id","ID").withColumnRenamed("max(calories_burnt)","Max_Calorias") 

df_MinimasCalorias = df_MinimasCalorias.withColumnRenamed("min(calories_burnt)","Min_Calorias") df_MediaCalorias = df_MediaCalorias.withColumnRenamed("avg(calories_burnt)","Media_Calorias")
```

## Create join expression

```
joinExpression = df_MaximasCalorias["ID"] == df_MinimasCalorias['user_id']
```

## First join

```
dfCalorias = df_MaximasCalorias.join(df_MinimasCalorias, joinExpression, "inner").select("ID","Max_Calorias","Min_Calorias") dfCalorias.show()
```

## Show Data. Works perfect

```
display(dfCalorias)
```

## Now join the new data frame `dfCalorias` with `df_MediaCalorias`

```
joinExpression = dfCalorias["ID"] == df_MediaCalorias['user_id'] 



dfCaloriasFinal = dfCalorias.join(df_MediaCalorias, joinExpression, "inner").select("ID","Max_Calorias","Min_Calorias","Media_Calorias")
```

## Error at this code

```
display(dfCaloriasFinal)
```

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate the detailed question! I'm pretty sure your error is this statement

```
joinExpression = dfCalorias["ID"] == df_MediaCalorias['user_id']
```

which sets `joinExpression` to a boolean value, since you're setting it equal to a comparison. You're better off writing your join equation in the function itself

```
dfCaloriasFinal = dfCalorias.join(df_MediaCalorias, dfCalorias["ID"] == df_MediaCalorias['user_id'], "inner").select("ID","Max_Calorias","Min_Calorias","Media_Calorias")
```